# Requires clause with pure abstract class type parameter?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, abstract-class, c++20, c++-concepts

Consider the following simple `concept`:

```
template <typename T>
concept C = requires(T a) { a.f(); };
```

What should happens if we take an *abstract class* type as the *requires expressions*'s argument?

```
struct B { virtual void f() = 0; };

static_assert(C<B>);
```

gcc-trunk and msvc-trunk **pass** the assertion, however, clang-trunk, gcc-10.2, and msvc v19.24 [**reject**](https://godbolt.org/z/bocWzK) the assertion.

What does the standard say?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GCC-trunk and MSVC-trunk are correct. The restrictions on the use of abstract types have *changed* between C++17 and C++20 thanks to [P0929](https://wg21.link/P0929). Consequently, even ordinary function declarations with abstract parameter types are now allowed:

```
void foo(B b);  // ill-formed in C++17, well-formed in C++20
void foo(B b) { /* ... */ }  // still ill-formed in C++20
```

The wording "An abstract class shall not be used as a parameter type..." (C++17 [class.abstract]/3) was removed. In C++20, it is ill-formed for a function to have an abstract parameter type only if the function is being called ([expr.call]/7) or defined ([dcl.fct.def.general]/2). Furthermore, a *parameter-declaration* found in a *requires-parameter-list* is not a definition, just like how a *parameter-declaration* found in a non-defining declaration of a function is not a definition ([basic.def]/2.8).

Comment: The reason for this apparently useless relaxation is that functions can be declared with parameter types that are **incomplete** classes; it would be problematic for a subsequent definition of the class as abstract to retroactively invalidate the function declaration.